# How to set text to be at the right side of the screen

Tags: html

I'm trying to replicate the front page of Fanfiction.Net as a personal assignment for myself but I don't know how to place the text in different places in the screen (Left, Center and Right all on the same line)

```css
body {
  background-color: lightyellow
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue">
  <table align="left">
    <tr>
      <hi style="color: white">Fanfiction.NET| Unleash your Imagination</hi>
    </tr>
    <tr style=""><input type="text" placeholder="Search.."></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the search bar appear at the right side of the header but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on this! Should explain everything you need. (Put it inside `style=""`)
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

Comment: i need it all to be on the same line

Comment: I believe <nobr> does this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of good HTML structure and styling. Part of the styling is using text-align: left or right but you will also need to structure your code the right way.

Right now you're using a table to structure your page. This is "HTML abuse" from the old days when we where very limited. These days a table is just used for displaying data (like you would expect from a table), not to style your page. For this we use other elements like divs. Of course it's very understandable that you want to order your page in columns. So you can still do that by telling your divs that they need to behave like a grid. And inside that grid you can put other divs that will behave like columns. See the example below.

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;  
}

.blue-bar { 
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 153);
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 80%; /* Or 1300px or 780px or ... just not the whole thing */
  margin: auto; /* If width is not 100% margin auto will position it in the middle */
  
  display: grid; /* Defines that we'll use a grid-system in this div */
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%; /* inside our grid-container are 2 divs, for 2 columns. these are their sizes */
}

.column-left {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Remove this, just visual help */
  text-align: left;
}

.column-right {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* Remove this, just visual help */
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-bar">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="column-left">FanFiction  |  unleash your imagination</div>
    <div class="column-right"> Login | Sign up </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you just started to learn HTML don't make the mistake to make your grids to complex. Just focus on a grid with one row and maybe two, three or four columns. (like the example of the topbar). Don't be to hasty to add rows in the beginning, those can get pretty confusing!